# Compare cell value with cell value below in same column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following column

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
```

I want to create a column that uses `df['num'].shift()` to compare the current cell value with the cell value below it, and if it matches then the value should be in True or False.

The expected output:

```
   num  matches?
0    1     False
1    2      True
2    2     False
3    3     False
4    4     False
5    5     False
6    6     False
```

I am not able to find the best way to iterate through each cell and compare the condition and when I use the following:

```
df['matches?'] = ''

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['num'] == df['num'].shift(1):
        df['matches?'] = True
    else:
        df['matches?'] = False
```

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How to achieve this in the simplest manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `shift` you do not need to loop, the operation is vectorized and does that for you:

```py
df['matches?'] = df['num'].shift(-1)==df['num']
```

Outputs:

```py
    num    matches?
0   1      False
1   2      True
2   2      False
3   3      False
4   4      False
5   5      False
6   6      False
```

**Edit**

If you want to keep the loop logic:

```py
for ix, row in df.iterrows():
    if ix < len(df)-1:
        if df.loc[ix, 'num'] == df.loc[ix+1, 'num']:
            df.loc[ix, 'matches?'] = True
        else:
            df.loc[ix, 'matches?'] = False
    else: #last observation
        df.loc[ix, 'matches?'] = False
```

Outputs:

```py
    num    matches?
0   1      False
1   2      True
2   2      False
3   3      False
4   4      False
5   5      False
6   6      False
```

Comment: Thanks, calestini. Can you show me a way of doing with `itertuples` and having an `if else` condition, as I have greatly simplified what my actual data looks like.

Comment: Keep in mind that [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) does not recommend to change a dataframe as you iterate through it.

Answer (score 3):

As you are working with numeric values, you could use `diff` to do the calculation between two rows, see code below

```
df['matches?'] = df['num'].diff(-1).eq(0)  #eq means equal to
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the for loop as is. You can try this

```
i=0
for i in range(0,len(df)-1):
    if df['num'][i] == df['num'][i+1]:
        df['matches?'][i] = "T"
    else:
        df['matches?'][i] = "F"
```

> You should iterate through `len(df)-1` because when the loop reaches last row, there will be nothing to compare after it. It will throw index error there.

**Output**

```
+-----+----------+
| num | matches? |
+-----+----------+
|   1 | F        |
|   2 | T        |
|   2 | F        |
|   3 | F        |
|   4 | F        |
|   5 | F        |
|   6 | F        |
+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add elif and implement by breaking the logic 3 sections like mentioned below

```
df['matches?'] = ''

for i in range(0,len(df['num'])):
    if i+1==len(df['num']):
       df['matches?'][i] = False
    elif df['num'][i] == df['num'][i+1]:
       df['matches?'][i] = True
    else:
       df['matches?'][i] = False
```